# How do I install tensorflow in a Docker image w/ venv?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I have the following code...

```
FROM python:latest
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV "/venv"
RUN python -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH "$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# Python commands run inside the virtual environment
RUN /venv/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN /venv/bin/pip3 install tensorflow
```

But when I run I get...

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I tried using the tensorflow image like...

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV "/venv"
RUN python -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH "$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# Python commands run inside the virtual environment
RUN /venv/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

but then I get...

```
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv
```

So I change to

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest
RUN apt-get install python3-venv -y
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV "/venv"
RUN python -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH "$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# Python commands run inside the virtual environment
RUN /venv/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

But I get...

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python3.6/python3.6-venv_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

How do I handle this?

Comment: Add `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` as your first `RUN`

Comment: Any idea how to install it using the python image instead?

Answer (score 0):

Per @drum comment this works...

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install python3-venv -y
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV "/venv"
RUN python -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH "$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# Python commands run inside the virtual environment
RUN /venv/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```